# Lenovo Legion 7 Linux suspend does not wake up

Tags: linux, suspend, laptop

On a Lenovo Legion 7 laptop with Ubuntu 20.04:

When I close the lid, laptop shuts all lights down and gets quiet. When lid is re-opened, the keyboard lights turn on, and also the fan, but not the display.

Additional info:

Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) has no effect.
Also after re-opening lid I can NOT connect from other pc to it via SSH (which works otherwise), so it is obviously NOT purely video problem, instead the system is not recovering at all. The only signs of life are the keyboard lights and the fan.
The drive encryption is set up in BIOS.
Same effect (non-recovery) happens if I suspend the laptop from UI.

Comment: First approach: I would ensure a persistent journal by `mkdir /var/log/journal`, then look for relevant messages after suspending and waking up. My hope is that you find kernel messages and/or messages issued by whatever daemon(s) manage the lid in Ubuntu 20.

Comment: I'd also try the command line, such as `systemctl hibernate` or `systemctl suspend`, and see if the laptop comes back. Also, I found [low-level configuration tips](https://www.linux.com/news/how-suspend-and-hibernate-laptop-under-linux/) on linux.com.